# Issue with Selection dropdown when it is 'required'

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the 'required' tag in HTML to validate input. However, I am having an error with the the selection. It does not show the option nor am I able to continue.

```js
const slidePage = document.querySelector(".slide-page");
const nextBtnFirst = document.querySelector(".firstNext");
const prevBtnSec = document.querySelector(".prev-1");
const nextBtnSec = document.querySelector(".next-1");
const prevBtnThird = document.querySelector(".prev-2");
const nextBtnThird = document.querySelector(".next-2");
const prevBtnFourth = document.querySelector(".prev-3");
const submitBtn = document.querySelector(".submit");
const progressText = document.querySelectorAll(".step p");
const progressCheck = document.querySelectorAll(".step .check");
const bullet = document.querySelectorAll(".step .bullet");
let current = 1;

nextBtnFirst.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  slidePage.style.marginLeft = "-25%";
  bullet[current - 1].classList.add("active");
  progressCheck[current - 1].classList.add("active");
  progressText[current - 1].classList.add("active");
  current += 1;
});
nextBtnSec.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  slidePage.style.marginLeft = "-50%";
  bullet[current - 1].classList.add("active");
  progressCheck[current - 1].classList.add("active");
  progressText[current - 1].classList.add("active");
  current += 1;
});
nextBtnThird.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  slidePage.style.marginLeft = "-75%";
  bullet[current - 1].classList.add("active");
  progressCheck[current - 1].classList.add("active");
  progressText[current - 1].classList.add("active");
  current += 1;
});
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  bullet[current - 1].classList.add("active");
  progressCheck[current - 1].classList.add("active");
  progressText[current - 1].classList.add("active");
  current += 1;
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert("Your Consultation Successfully Submitted");
    location.reload();
  }, 800);
});

prevBtnSec.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  slidePage.style.marginLeft = "0%";
  bullet[current - 2].classList.remove("active");
  progressCheck[current - 2].classList.remove("active");
  progressText[current - 2].classList.remove("active");
  current -= 1;
});
prevBtnThird.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  slidePage.style.marginLeft = "-25%";
  bullet[current - 2].classList.remove("active");
  progressCheck[current - 2].classList.remove("active");
  progressText[current - 2].classList.remove("active");
  current -= 1;
});
prevBtnFourth.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  slidePage.style.marginLeft = "-50%";
  bullet[current - 2].classList.remove("active");
  progressCheck[current - 2].classList.remove("active");
  progressText[current - 2].classList.remove("active");
  current -= 1;
});



let data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Management",
    "parentid": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Support",
    "parentid": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Digital Business",
    "parentid": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Cyber Security",
    "parentid": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Infrastructure",
    "parentid": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Network",
    "parentid": 0
  },



  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "MDM Solution",
    "parentid": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "IT Procurement",
    "parentid": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Vendor Management",
    "parentid": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Managed servers, Network, Firewall",
    "parentid": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Backup and Storage",
    "parentid": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "name": "Email Management",
    "parentid": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "name": "Microsoft Office Management",
    "parentid": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "Asset Management",
    "parentid": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "name": "Network Management",
    "parentid": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "name": "Communication Management",
    "parentid": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "name": "Patch Management",
    "parentid": 1
  },


  {
    "id": 18,
    "name": "IT Helpdesk",
    "parentid": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 19,
    "name": "Maintenance of Servers",
    "parentid": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 20,
    "name": "Network Maintenance",
    "parentid": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "name": "Communication Maintenance",
    "parentid": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "name": "Patch Management",
    "parentid": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "name": "Disaster Recovery Testing and Support",
    "parentid": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "name": "Pro-active Capacity Planning and Support",
    "parentid": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "name": "Remote and Onsite Support",
    "parentid": 2
  },



  {
    "id": 25,
    "name": "Office 365 Migration",
    "parentid": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "name": "Managed Offsite Backups",
    "parentid": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 27,
    "name": "Azure Migration & Uplift",
    "parentid": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 28,
    "name": "SaaS Products Support ",
    "parentid": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 29,
    "name": "Microsoft Teams Setup",
    "parentid": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 30,
    "name": "SharePoint Configuration",
    "parentid": 3
  },



  {
    "id": 32,
    "name": "Risk Assessment",
    "parentid": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 33,
    "name": "Cloud base & on prem SIEM Solution Implementation",
    "parentid": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 34,
    "name": "Vulnerability & penetration testing",
    "parentid": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 35,
    "name": "Cyber Security Incident Response Plan",
    "parentid": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 36,
    "name": "Cloud Security",
    "parentid": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 37,
    "name": "CyberArk PAM solution",
    "parentid": 4
  },


  {
    "id": 38,
    "name": "SME Upgrades and Consolidation",
    "parentid": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 39,
    "name": "Dell Networking",
    "parentid": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 40,
    "name": "Data Centre Design",
    "parentid": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 41,
    "name": "Storage Design and Installation",
    "parentid": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 42,
    "name": "Disaster Recovery Infrastructure",
    "parentid": 5
  },



  {
    "id": 43,
    "name": "Redundancy Planning",
    "parentid": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 44,
    "name": "Internet and WAN Connectivity Design",
    "parentid": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 45,
    "name": "Cabling Design",
    "parentid": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 46,
    "name": "Network Switching Design and Scale",
    "parentid": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 47,
    "name": "Routing Design ",
    "parentid": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 48,
    "name": "Firewall Design and Maintenance ",
    "parentid": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 49,
    "name": "Fibre, Cat5, Cat6 and WiFi Planning and Installation",
    "parentid": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 50,
    "name": "Access Network Design ",
    "parentid": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 51,
    "name": "Automation Workflows and Software Development",
    "parentid": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 52,
    "name": "Campus Network Design",
    "parentid": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 53,
    "name": "ISP Network Design",
    "parentid": 6
  },

]

function populateList(list, pid) {
  let l = document.getElementById(list);
  l.innerHTML = "";
  let topItem = document.createElement("option");
  topItem.value = 0;
  topItem.text = "--Select--";
  l.appendChild(topItem);
  let items = data.filter(item => item.parentid == pid);
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    let newItem = document.createElement("option");
    newItem.value = item.id;
    newItem.text = item.name;
    l.appendChild(newItem);
  })
}

function updateList(selList, thisList) {
  if (thisList.value != 0) {
    populateList(selList, Number(thisList.value));
  } else {
    let s = document.getElementById(selList);
    s.value = 0;
    triggerEvent(s, "onchange");
    let sCopy = s.cloneNode(false);
    let p = s.parentNode;
    p.replaceChild(sCopy, s);
  }
}

function triggerEvent(e, trigger) {
  if ((e[trigger] || false) && typeof e[trigger] == 'function') {
    e[trigger](e);
  }
}


function loadList1() {
  populateList("list1", 0);
}

window.onload = loadList1;



if (FullNameValue === '') {
  setErrorFor(FullName, FullName 'Full Name cannot be blank');
}
```

```css
::selection {
  color: #fffef8;
  background: #4197a9;
}

.container {
  width: 750px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 50px 35px 10px 35px;
}

.container header {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  right: auto;
}

.container .form-outer {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

.container .form-outer form {
  display: flex;
  width: 600%;
}

.form-outer form .page {
  width: 25%;
  transition: margin-left 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.form-outer form .page .title {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.form-outer form .page .field {
  width: 800px;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 90px 0;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

form .page .field .label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

form .page .field input {
  height: 80%;
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid #33343d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

form .page .field select {
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

form .page .field button {
  width: 250px;
  height: calc(100% + 5px);
  border: none;
  background: #4197a9;
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

form .page .field button:hover {
  background: #000;
}

form .page .btns button {
  margin-top: -20px!important;
}

form .page .btns button.prev {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

form .page .btns button.next {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.container .progress-bar {
  display: flex;
  user-select: none;
  left: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

.container .progress-bar .step {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.container .progress-bar .step p {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.progress-bar .step .bullet {
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.2s;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.progress-bar .step .bullet.active {
  border-color: #4197a9;
  background: #4197a9;
}

.progress-bar .step .bullet span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.progress-bar .step .bullet.active span {
  display: none;
}

.progress-bar .step .bullet:before,
.progress-bar .step .bullet:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 11px;
  right: -51px;
  left: 50px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
}

.progress-bar .step .bullet.active:after {
  background: #4197a9;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  animation: animate 0.3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

.progress-bar .step:last-child .bullet:before,
.progress-bar .step:last-child .bullet:after {
  display: none;
}

.progress-bar .step p.active {
  color: #d43f8d;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.progress-bar .step .check {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 70%;
  font-size: 15px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: none;
}

.progress-bar .step .check.active {
  display: block;
  color: #fffef8;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="step">
    <p>
      Name</p>
    <div class="bullet">
      <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="check fas fa-check">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <p>
      Contact</p>
    <div class="bullet">
      <span>2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="check fas fa-check">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <p>
      Service</p>
    <div class="bullet">
      <span>3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="check fas fa-check">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <p>
      Submit</p>
    <div class="bullet">
      <span>4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="check fas fa-check">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-outer">
  <form action="#">
    <div class="page slide-page">
      <div class="title">
        Lets get Started
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">








        <div class="field">
          <div class="label">
            Full Name </div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="FirstName SecondName " id="FullName" required>

        </div>





        <div class="field">
          <div class="label">
            Company Name</div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="comname" required>

        </div>





        <div class="field">
          <button class="firstNext next" style="position: relative; left: 280px;">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>







    </div>







    <div class="page">
      <div class="title">
        Contact Info:</div>
      <div class="field">
        <div class="label">
          Email Address</div>

        <input type="email" placeholder="name@example.com" required>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <div class="label">
          Phone Number</div>
        <input type="number" placeholder="+61 412 345 678" required>
      </div>
      <div class="field btns">
        <button class="prev-1 prev">Previous</button>
        <button class="next-1 next">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="page">
      <div class="title">
        Services</div>
      <div class="field">
        <div class="label">
          Service Category</div>
        <select id="list1" onchange="updateList('list2', this);" required>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <div class="label">
          Service</div>
        <select id="list2" onchange="updateList('list3', this);" required></select>

      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <div class="label">
          Description

        </div>
        <textarea name="Description" id="" cols="75" rows="100" style="height:60px;" placeholder="Provide a small description about the service you have selected."></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="field btns">
        <button class="prev-2 prev" style="position: relative; left: 30px;">Previous</button>
        <button class="next-2 next" style="position: relative; left: 30px;">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="title">
        Submit</div>
      <div class="field">
        <div class="label">
          Pefered method of Communication</div>
        <select name="communica" id="" required>
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="Phone">Phone </option>
          <option value="Email ">Email </option>
          <option value="SMS">SMS </option>

        </select>


      </div>
      <div class="textsub" style="position: relative; left: 0; margin-right: 400px;">
        We will reach out to you with some proposal and we will discuss which will be the best for you while hearing your feedback. You should recieve an email within 24 hours with what will be happening. Thank you
      </div>
      <div class="field btns">
        <button class="prev-3 prev">Previous</button>
        <button class="submit" style="left: 50px; position: relative;">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

I have included the relevant code below.

```
<select id="list1" onchange="updateList('list2', this);" required >
      </select>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
               <div class="label">
                Service</div>
      <select id="list2" onchange="updateList('list3', this);" required ></select>

                  </div>
```

Comment: well, IT'S EMPTY!

Comment: nono, this list is linked to javascript. the list goes blank when i add required but if i dont the selection works normally. check the link

Comment: Your code does throw a syntax error on this line `setErrorFor(FullName, FullName 'Full Name cannot be blank');` which is missing a comma. Try fixing the syntax errors first and see if it works, because there's a lot of code here